# Spring data mongodb hierarchy

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I have a nested json object in a hierarchical structure as defined below

```
[
    {
        "categoryId": 1,
        "categoryName": "Category 1",
        "childCategory": null,
        "active": false
    },
    {
        "categoryId": 2,
        "categoryName": "Category 2",
        "active": true,
        "childCategory": [
            {
                "categoryId": 4,
                "categoryName": "Category 4",
                "childCategory": null,
                "active": false
            },
            {
                "categoryId": 5,
                "categoryName": "Category 5",
                "childCategory": null,
                "active": true
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "categoryId": 10,
        "categoryName": "Category 10",
        "childCategory": null,
        "active": true
    }
]
```

From this I want to select all the active categories to a single array structure. My output should be

```
[
    {
        "categoryId": 2,
        "categoryName": "Category 2",
        "active": true
    },
    {
        "categoryId": 5,
        "categoryName": "Category 5",
        "active": true
    },
    {
        "categoryId": 10,
        "categoryName": "Category 10",
        "active": true
    }
]
```

Is it possible to directly fetch this data in a single query statement. I am using spring data for mongodb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation.

`$redact` to go through a document level at a time and perform `$$DESCEND` and `$$PRUNE` on the matching criteria.

`$unwind` the `$childCategory` with `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` to keep the array with `null` values.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $redact: {
        $cond: [{
            $eq: ["$active", true]
        }, "$$DESCEND", "$$PRUNE"]
    }
}, {
    $unwind: {
        path: "$childCategory",
        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
})
```